# store JBoss port in DB

Tags: configuration, jboss, configuration-management

I have been doing research on how I can store ports info (e.g RMI, http port etc) in database instead of storing in system/env variable or in jboss-service.xml. However, I am unable to find any. 
I understand I can store, get port info from DB and then dump port info into system/env variables. however I would like to know if there are any built-in and/or 3rd party lib/api which already have the capability to get port info from a DB and jboss can auto pick up and no need to set as system/env variables.
Hope someone can help solving the puzzle.

Thanks
-A

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that some ready-out-of-the-box tool exists for such specific task.

If the intent is to simplify the process of configuration then you might prefer to use some [configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) [management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software) tool. One of the best is [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am actually looking to store the port info in the DB instead of env variables. I didn't mean to config DB in JBoss.